# Writing string variables in if-else statements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, boolean

This might be a trivial problem but I want to write a simple for loop in Matlab that uses string variables for the different cases.

In Python, it is simply,

```
from numpy import cos, sin, pi

dist = 'markovian'

x = pi/7

if dist == 'lorentzian':
    z = sin(x)
    print(z)
elif dist == 'markovian':
    z = cos(x)
    print(z)
else:
    z = sin(x) + cos(x)
    print(z)
```

whereas in Matlab I have tried

```
dist = 'markovian';

x = pi/7;

if dist == strcmpi('lorentzian','true')
    z = sin(x)
elseif dist == strcmpi('markovian','true')
    z = cos(x)
else
    z = sin(x) + cos(x)
end
```

but it doesn't calculate `z`. What am I doing wrong with `strcmpi`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `strcmpi` with `if` / `else`

The function [`strcmpi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) compares two strings ignoring case and returns a logical value. Thus, you need to use it as follows:

```
dist = 'markovian';
x = pi/7;
if strcmpi(dist, 'lorentzian')
    z = sin(x)
elseif strcmpi(dist, 'markovian')
    z = cos(x)
else
    z = sin(x) + cos(x)
end
```

### Using `switch`

The code may be clearer with a [`switch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement. You can use [`lower`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to achieve case insensitivity.

```
dist = 'markovian';
x = pi/7;
switch lower(dist)
    case 'lorentzian'
        z = sin(x)
    case 'markovian'
        z = cos(x)
    otherwise
        z = sin(x) + cos(x)
end
```

### Without branching

Here is an alternative that avoids branching. If you only have two or three options this approach is unnecesarily complicated, but if there are many options it may be more adequate for compactness or even readability.

This works by finding the index of the chosen option in a cell array of char vectors, if present; and using [`feval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html) to evaluate the corresponding function from a cell array of function handles:

```
names = {'lorentzian', 'markovian'}; % names: cell array of char vectors
funs = {@(x)sin(x), @(x)cos(x), @(x)sin(x)+cos(x)}; % functions: cell array of handles.
                                                    % Note there is one more than names
dist = 'markovian';
x = pi/7;
[~, ind] = ismember(lower(dist), names); % index of dist in names
ind = ind + (ind==0)*numel(funs); % if 0 (dist not in names), select last function
feval(funs{ind}, x)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option in MATLAB >= R2016b is to use `string` rather than `char` for text data. `string` lets you compare using `==`, like this:

```
dist = "markovian"

x = pi/7

if dist == "lorentzian"
    z = sin(x)
elseif dist == "markovian"
    z = cos(x)
else
    z = sin(x) + cos(x)
end
```

Comment: Hm, not _entirely_ clear to me they wanted case-insensitive - surely `==` is case-sensitive in Python? That appeared to me to be their starting point.

Comment: You are right. Python's `==`  is case-sensitive, but Matlab's `strcmpi` is not. So it's not clear what they wanted